# Buffer length grows in stream cipher

Tags: c#, encryption, stream, buffer

The size is growing if the bytes I read are encrypted.

How can I find the value of the bytes I read when I try to decrypt.

For example:

BufferLengh: 8192

After encrypting: 8208

The 16 byte difference there is not fixed.

How can I make this process stable
I look forward to your different solutions and recommendations

**Encrypting Function**:

```
using (FileStream TEMPFILE = new FileStream(FILE_FULL_NAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, BUFFER_SIZE, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{
    int BUFFER_SIZE=8192;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while ((bytesRead = FILE_ORGINAL.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        byte[] cryp = EN_Crypto_AES(buffer); 

        //encryp lenth  : 8208
        //BUFFER_SIZE   : 8192
        //----------------------
        //Crypto         +16 byte

        TEMPFILE.Write(cryp, 0, cryp.Length);
    }

    TEMPFILE.Position = 0;
    TEMPFILE.CopyTo(FILE_ORGINAL);
}
```

**Decrypting Function**

```
using (FileStream TEMPFILE = new FileStream(FILE_FULL_NAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, BUFFER_SIZE, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{
    int BUFFER_SIZE=8192;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while ((bytesRead = FILE_ORGINAL.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        byte[] cryp = DE_Crypto_AES(buffer); //16 byte ? 

        TEMPFILE.Write(cryp, 0, cryp.Length);
    }

    TEMPFILE.Position = 0;
    TEMPFILE.CopyTo(FILE_ORGINAL);
}
```

**EDIT**

***Another class***

```
byte[] passwordBytes;

public byte[] EN_Crypto_AES(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return encryptedBytes;
}
public byte[] DE_Crypto_AES(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted)
{
    byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

    // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
    // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return decryptedBytes;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post the code for `EN_Crypto_AES`.

Answer (score 0):

AES is not a stream cipher, it can be used as a stream cipher in CTR mode.

The additional bytes are padding. See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

Block ciphers require input to be an exact multiple of the block size, this is generally accomplished with PKCS#7 padding. By specifying padding (many times the default) the padding bytes are automatically added during encryption and removed during decryption.

The block size of AES is 16-bytes and it padding is used it must be added even when the input data is already an exact multiple of the block size.

Comment: Thank you. I know it's a standard 16 bytes. This is just an example. How do I resolve an operation in this logic?

Comment: AES is not a stream cipher in the CBC mode. What is the problem with the padding bytes being added?

Comment: I can not decrypt the problem

Comment: Are you getting an error or is the data just incorrect? But you are asking the wrong question, the question seems to really about decryption failing.

Comment: BUFFER_SIZE=8192+16; do not have any problems. But it is not an accurate encoding.

Comment: 1. What error message, exactly. 2. What does "not an accurate encoding" mean? 3. Suggestion: add more information to the question.